When I try to calculate FFT I get an error
I have implemented a c++ program that calculates the fast Fourier transform, but for some reason it does not work. Can you tell me what the problem is?
I split tasks between threads and get them in the zero thread. But an error pops up during the calculation. mpi.exe ended prematurely and may have crashed. exit code 0xc0000374. I don't understand why the program crashes.
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <mpi.h>

#define PI 3.14159265

struct num1
{
    float real;
    float img;
};

int reverseBits(int number, int NO_OF_BITS)
{
    int reverse_num = 0, i, temp;
    for (i = 0; i < NO_OF_BITS; i++)
    {
        temp = (number & (1 << i));
        if (temp)
            reverse_num |= (1 << ((NO_OF_BITS - 1) - i));
    }
    return reverse_num;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int rank, size, num, i, key, div;
    double bb1time, ab1time, bb2time, ab2time, starttime, endtime;

    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    MPI_Datatype num1type;
    MPI_Datatype type[2] = { MPI_FLOAT, MPI_FLOAT };

    int blocklen[2] = { 4, 4 };

    MPI_Aint disp[2];

    num = 256;

    bb1time = MPI_Wtime();
    MPI_Bcast(&num, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    ab1time = MPI_Wtime();

    struct num1* input = new num1[num + 1];
    struct num1* seq = new num1[num + 1];
    struct num1* temp = new num1[num + 1];

    input[0].real = 0.0;
    input[0].img = 0.0;
    seq[0].real = 0.0;
    seq[0].img = 0.0;
    temp[0].real = 0.0;
    temp[0].img = 0.0;

    disp[0] = 0;
    disp[1] = 4;
    

    MPI_Type_create_struct(2, blocklen, disp, type, &num1type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&num1type);

    if (rank == 0)
    {
        bb1time = MPI_Wtime();
        srand(time(NULL));
        for (i = 1; i < num + 1; i++)
        {
            input[i].real = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
            input[i].img = 0.0;
        }

        for (i = 1; i < num + 1; i++)
        {
            seq[i].real = input[reverseBits(i - 1, log2(num) / log2(2)) + 1].real;
            seq[i].img = 0.0;
        }
    }

    bb2time = MPI_Wtime();
    MPI_Bcast(seq, num + 1, num1type, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    ab2time = MPI_Wtime();

    key = log2(num);
    div = 1;

    starttime = MPI_Wtime();

    while (key--)
    {
        if (rank != 0)
        {
            if (((rank + div - 1) / div) % 2 == 0)
            {
                temp[rank].real = seq[rank - div].real +
                    (cos(PI * ((rank - 1) % (div * 2)) / div) * (seq[rank].real)) +
                    (sin(PI * ((rank - 1) % (div * 2)) / div) * (seq[rank].img));

                temp[rank].img = seq[rank - div].img +
                    (cos(PI * ((rank - 1) % (div * 2)) / div) * (seq[rank].img)) -
                    (sin(PI * ((rank - 1) % (div * 2)) / div) * (seq[rank].real));

                MPI_Send(&temp[rank], 1, num1type, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            }
            else
            {
                temp[rank].real = seq[rank].real +
                    (cos(PI * ((rank - 1) % (div * 2)) / div) * (seq[rank + div].real)) +
                    (sin(PI * ((rank - 1) % (div * 2)) / div) * (seq[rank + div].img));

                temp[rank].img = seq[rank].img +
                    (cos(PI * ((rank - 1) % (div * 2)) / div) * (seq[rank + div].img)) -
                    (sin(PI * ((rank - 1) % (div * 2)) / div) * (seq[rank + div].real));

                MPI_Send(&temp[rank], 1, num1type, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (i = 1; i < num; i++) {
                MPI_Recv(&temp[i], 1, num1type, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            }
        }

        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        if (rank == 0)
        {
            for (i = 1; i < num + 1; i++)
            {
                seq[i].real = temp[i].real;
                seq[i].img = temp[i].img;
            }
            div *= 2;
        }

        MPI_Bcast(seq, num + 1, num1type, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Bcast(&div, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    endtime = MPI_Wtime();

    if (0 == rank)
    {
        std::cout << std::endl;

        for (i = 1; i < num + 1; i++)
        {
            std::cout << "X[" << i - 1 << "] : " << seq[i].real;

            if (seq[i].img >= 0)
                std::cout << "+j" << seq[i].img << std::endl;
            else
                std::cout << "-j" << seq[i].img - 2 * seq[i].img << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Time to broadcast num variable: " << (ab1time - bb1time) * 1000 << " ms" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Time to broadcast input and seq arrays: " << (ab2time - bb2time) * 1000 << " ms" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Time to compute FFT parallely: " << (endtime - starttime) * 1000 << " ms" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Total Time: " << ((endtime - starttime) + (ab2time - bb2time) + (ab1time - bb1time)) * 1000 << " ms" << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}

I think problem in section when we're receiving results of computation from all processes. I don't understand how correctly to get data.

0xc0000374 means heap memory corruption. Replace all raw arrays with std::vector and use .at(i) instead of [i]. Compile your program with the address sanitizer enabled.

blocklen is in units of MPI_FLOAT so it should be {1,1}. As a matter of style, you can use the offsetof() macro to populate the disp array.

@273K same error mpi.exe ended prematurely and may have crashed. exit code 0xc0000374

@GillesGouaillardet after this action program don't respond.

so edit your question and append your new code. If it hangs instead of crashing, that could be a memory corruption or a very different issue.

How many MPI processes do you use? I think you will need 256 processes to not deadlock. Rank 0 expects 255 messages, and each other process sends just one message. Also, does it make sense to store the result in a random order at the root process?
